# visible hyphen char, why?

Tags: luatex

The pdf output of the following small example document is wrong if compiled with `lualatex` (Version beta-0.80.0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% {2016/02/01}{2.5a} 
\begin{document}
lm – Latin mod­ern fonts in out­line for­mats
\end{document}
```

The hidden hyphen chars (unicode soft hyphen; html entity `&#xad;`) are visible but should not. The output looks like

```
lm – Latin mod-ern fonts in out-line for-­mats
```

The text was copied from the CTAN web site:

```
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm
```

The same example compiled with `xelatex` gives correct output. I use an up-to-date TeXLive on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If you are expecting that the soft-hyphen character means something to XeTeX/LuaTeX, you're wrong, I'm afraid.

It's true that it isn't visible with XeTeX, but this doesn't mean it works.

However, you can define the character to stand for `\-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}                    

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{­}{\-}

\begin{document}

lm – Latin mod­ern fonts in out­line for­mats

\parbox[t]{0pt}{
lm – Latin mod­ern fonts in out­line for­mats
}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` is to show as many hyphenation points as possible.

[image]

Try commenting the `\newunicodechar` line and you'll see that *no* word will be hyphenated.

Comment: Thanks for confirming whether the XeTeX behaviour was sensible. I wonder if this would be a sensible char to special case for being active… (along with no-break-space, etc.)

Comment: @WillRobertson I guess so, unless Arthur and Hans find a way for making it behave as expected as part of the line breaking algorithm (unlikely for XeTeX, I believe). It's important soft-hyphen behaves so, because text copied from other sources might contain it.

Comment: couldn't XeTeX use its `\XeTeXinterchartoks` here ?

Comment: @jfbu Possible, but too complicated: you'd have to take care of newly defined classes, for instance. Making it active is not really different from what's done for `~`.

Comment: Actually I'm confused. If the engine isn't doing anything to it, shouldn't it display the glyph for U+00AD, which presumably isn't a copy of the hyphen in the font? Or is it, and xetex is set up to just ignore the char?

Comment: @WillRobertson That I don't know. `;-)` But I guess that showing or not U+00AD is a decision by the software.

Comment: @egreg I expect that the soft-hyphen character is treated in the same way as `\-` without need of `\newunicodechar`.

Comment: @rolfn Well, it isn't.

Comment: context makes the U+00AD active and maps it to a command `\softhyphen`. It would probably quite sensible if the xe/lua-latex formats would do this by default too.